# Possible numeric error for large/smalll values numpy

Tags: python, numpy, physics

I was trying to *mimic* an infinite force when 2 particles come too close.

And the distance at which this starts depends on distance to sum radii of particles.

```
def dist(a,b):#working and tested for normal values
    d_sq = 0
    if len(a) == len(b):
        for i in range(len(a)):
            d_sq = d_sq + (a[i] - b[i])**2
        return (d_sq)**(1/2)


D = float((dist(prtc.rs[i], prtc.rs[j]))/(prtc.rads[i] + prtc.rads[j]))
if D <1 + 10**(-10):
                    #f[i,j] is force on i by j repulsive and poining from j to i
                    #we want the force to blow up at such a distance
                    fs[i, j] = (1/(D-1))*unit(prtc.rs[i] - prtc.rs[j])
                    fs[j, i] = - fs[i, j]
                    f[i] = f[i] + fs[i,j]
```

When the particles get close enough i.e. dist(prtc.rs[i], prtc.rs[j]) < 1 the type of D gets converted from float to np.ndarray of 2 elements I get this error message.

```
  File "C:/Users/karth/Desktop/code/kphys/BaseEngine.py", line 114, in timestep
    prtc.vs = prtc.vs + np.divide(interaction(), prtc.ms)

  File "C:/Users/karth/Desktop/code/kphys/BaseEngine.py", line 86, in interaction
    /(prtc.rads[i] + prtc.rads[j]))

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I believe the particles are getting too close than what the system can handle, please correct me if i'm wrong. If I am right does anyone know of any alternate implementation?

Comment: If you'r going to completely change your question, you'd do better to post it as a new one.  Nobody is looking at 5 day old questions.  Although it's still no precisely clear what is wrong without the full error trace and at least the surrounding lines of code in `BaseEngine.py`

Comment: Ok I'll reframe and make a new question, after much debugging problems seems to be appearing in the datatype python assigns to fs[i, j] and since it happens to be called only when particles are close enough that makes sense too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
File "C:/Users/karth/Desktop/code/kphys/BaseEngine.py", line 55, in dist
    return np.sqrt(d_sq)

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'sqrt'
```

that `AttributeError` is saying that a `float` object doesn't have an attribute `sqrt`.  An attribute is signified by `object.attribute` in `python`.  So it's saying that `np` is now a `float` object, and not a package object.

Somewhere in your program you have a variable `np` that you've set as a float.  After that, you don't have `numpy` anymore.  Maybe it only happens when particles get close enough, and that's why you're seeing it then.  But that appears to be the problem.  Check the source code of `BaseEngine.py`

Comment: That doesn't seem to be happening, if I check for type(np) it always gives <class 'module'> as output.

Comment: When the particles get closer than 1 the type of D changes float to np.ndarray.